# What does the term "breeder" mean in The Chronicles of Riddick?

Tags: terminology, the-chronicles-of-riddick, riddick-franchise

In The Chronicles of Riddick, both Vaako and his wife Dame Vaako refer to Riddick as a "breeder". Is this a race they are presuming he is a member of? I say "presuming" because later on

> it is discovered that he is actually a Furyan, but I don't think Vaako or his wife knew that at the time they were calling him a "breeder".

What does the term "breeder" mean in this movie?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the *Riddick* universe, Vaako and Dame Vaako are necromongers. Necromongers view life as an abberation to be corrected, and exist in a state where they are "one quarter dead." One side effect of this process is that it renders the subject sterile - after all, if you believe life is abhorrent, you don't want to be making more of it. (Sadly, I can't remember in which *Riddick* thing I read/saw/heard/played this.)

Calling Riddick a "breeder" is classifying him as someone who is capable of reproduction. It may also double as an epithet and insult as it describes an act considered immoral in necromonger culture.

Comment: Isn't this a slur that gays (used to? not anymore) use about heterosexuals? I think I was once called a breeder, decades before Riddick.